# How can I switch from Easypeasy to Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I have an Easypeasy install but as it is not being maintained, I would like to upgrade / switch to the normal Ubunutu distributions. Will that be possible just by editing sources.lst or will I need to backup my home folder, reformat and install ubuntu, then restore my home folder ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a much easier to just do a fresh installation of Ubuntu on your existing partitions. Installation process is simple and reliable. Messing with apt sources and upgrading - definitely not. So make a backup copy of your files and then install fresh Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.